Get Audio from live server
I create one project that ask user "What is you age?" then user response that name then it print the name
from flask import Flask, request
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
app = Flask(name)
user_name = None
@app.route('/ask_and_speak', methods=['POST'])
def ask_and_speak():
global user_name
# Use pyttsx3 to ask the user's name
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("Hello! What is your name?")
engine.runAndWait()

# Use SpeechRecognition to recognize the user's response
recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Listening...")
    audio = recognizer.listen(source)

try:
    # Recognize the user's response
    user_name = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
    print("User's name:", user_name)
    
    # Speak out the recognized name
    engine.say(f"Nice to meet you, {user_name}!")
    engine.runAndWait()
    
    return 'User name stored and spoken!'
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    return 'Sorry, I could not understand your response.'
except sr.RequestError:
    return 'Sorry, there was an error with the speech recognition service.'

if name == 'main':
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
What i want is i host this api in render. but now its giving me error to speak and in recognition
so there is any way to do this after host this api??
